# Background-Color of BODY tag applied to the whole HTML

Tags: html, css

I am confused about size of body tag in html.

I have a tough code as follows:

```
<body>

</body>
```

---

```
 body{
        padding: 0px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: #e5e5e5;
    }
```

Why does background cover all of the page?, I thought it should only cover 100px,

Please explain this for me, thank for your help!

Comment: @seemly: there was an invalid edit to the question, you can see question history, the OP asks why background was in fact applied to the whole page.

Comment: @seemly, try and understand the question. He wants to ask why does the Bg-color get applied to the whole page. Frankly speaking, aashnisshah's does not answer the question and it deviates from what answer the OP seek's

Comment: I am sorry, My English is very bad!!!

Comment: Thats fine. we are programmers, not Shakespeare's

Comment: add margin: 0; style to body, and there you go

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is indeed confusing, but it is specified in the CSS 2.1 specification, clause [14.2 Background](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background): if the computed value of `background-color` is `transparent` and the computed value of `background-image` is `none` for the `html` element (as things are by default), browsers must instead use the computed value of the background properties for the `body` element and must not render a background for `body` (i.e. make it transparent). That is, `body` background magically turns to `html` background if `html` lacks a background of its own – and this only affects background properties, not the true height of the `body` element.

I haven’t seen any rationale for this odd rule, which prescribes a kind of “reverse inheritance”. But it’s clearly specified in CSS 2.1 and applied by browsers.

As explained in other answers, you can make your content have a background of specific height either by setting a background on `html` (so that `body` background is really applied to `body` only) or by using wrapper element inside `body` and setting height on it (since the special rule applies to `body` only).

Thanks to Anne van Kesteren who pointed to the CSS spec when I asked about this in the WHATWG mailing list. (I thought I knew CSS 2.1 by heart but really didn’t. ☺)

Comment: This is the only true answer and explanation of the true reason of the issue. This answer should be the accepted one!

Comment: Also, at some point before 2009 this behavior was specified differently for HTML and XHTML documents, and old browsers behaved this way, but then the spec was changed: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.tech.css/HLBSyyITk_w

Comment: @Jukka Thank you, I read, but I didn't understand what is canvas!, can you explain for me?

Comment: Just revisited this question that I'd marked as a duplicate last year, as well as your answer. This behavior may have to do with the `background` and `bgcolor` presentational attributes that are defined on the body element. Also, your use of U+263A WHITE SMILING FACE is a nice respite from the colorful bitmap emoji that is all the rage these days.

Answer (score 3):

The body is a special HTML tag, and ordinarily covers the entire HTML page. Try the following:

```
<body>
    <div id="content">
        Content goes here
    </div>
</body>
```

and the CSS to accompany it would be:

```
body{
    /* whatever body related codes you'd like to use go here */
}

#content{
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
```

Comment: Here the height of the `body` element is set to 100px, and the question was why its background is still applied to the entire page.

Comment: The `body` element *does not* ordinarily cover the viewport. The background issue is the special case separately described in the CSS 2.1 spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#background

Answer (score 2):

Many web developers do not understand the difference between applying style to the body element versus the html element. Most of the time these authors will apply style only to the body element; when that's not sufficient, they'll spam all sorts of styles on both html and body until the page happens to look correct.

The confusion is understandable. In the beginning, both were treated similarly, with attributes like background-color being applied to the body tag, affecting the whole page.

EDIT: To simplify thing i have added a fiddle to demonstrate how the background-color gets applied.So if you specify the background color for the body and you **DONT** want it to spread to the whole page you must specify the background-color for HTML *too*

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7PJey/)

CSS

```
html{
    background-color:yellow;
}
body{
        padding: 0px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
    }
```

Comment: This does not answer the question (why the `body` background is applied to the whole page).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, Sometimes trivial things like this are best left unexplained. Now if we start giving explanations for "why is tea best served hot?", we would not make it to the end of the day, would we? Just kidding buddy. Frankly, i dont know. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should explicitly specify a [background color for the `html` tag](http://codepen.io/yardenst/pen/rapgm) (**as browsers add it automatically**), otherwise, the background of the `body` is spread all over the document.

Comment: This doesa not answer the “why” question.

Comment: Body is treated like html (because it the graphical representation of the document, html contains other stuff: <header>) so unless explicitly setting a css attribute to <html> it will act like the all page

Comment: That is what seems to be happening, but what is the explanation or excuse in HTML or CSS specifications? This only happens to the background. E.g., if you set a border on `body`, it is drawn around the box of the `body` element.