# Body width is not set?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to set the width of the body to 650px. But its not happening. 
Simple css code.

```
body{
    width:650px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

My HTML code!

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Login Successful <?php echo $_SESSION['username']?></h1>

</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the red color according to the code but not getting the width, as you see the pic.

Comment: Add your content css for checkwhere the issue. see http://jsfiddle.net/8eVrD/

Comment: Sorry didnt get you??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Background-Color of BODY tag applied to the whole HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806691/background-color-of-body-tag-applied-to-the-whole-html)

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap the page by `div` tag and set the height

```
.wrapper{
   width:650px;
   height:500px;
   background-color:red;
}
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
     <h1>Login Successful <?php echo $_SESSION['username']?></h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your **`body width is 650px`** for **`All content elements`**.

But body is magic element to set **`background-color`** all including outside margin.

Check this <kbd>**[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B4KbC/)**</kbd> , for show you border property to see difference,

---

But now same things you can done use **`div element`** inside body and apply width or background-color to check this <kbd>[**Demo jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/B4KbC/1/)</kbd> difference.

Answer (score 0):

The `<body>` element is magic. Wrap your *page* in a `<div>` and style that instead.