# Why background-attachment: fixed makes the gradient to appear on entire page?

Tags: html, css

I have studied 5 SO questions but they all talk about how to do it.

One question also talked about why background have special behavior on body and html tags.

But my question is: Why fixed attachment makes the gradient to appear on entire page?

I mean, lets take a 200 x 200 px image as a background. It will remain fixed even when we scroll the page. (assuming `background-attachment: fixed;` property is applied).

But when we add gradient as a background on body tag, it stretches to entire page. Now I have studied that gradients are supposed to work like that. OK I understand. But it does not appear on entire page when `background-attachment: fixed;` is not specified. It repeats instead.

Why does `background-attachment: fixed` makes the gradient to stretch on entire page? This doesn't happen when we use a plain image.

So my question is: why this behavior comes when we apply `background-attachment: fixed` property?

The ONLY behavior which should come is that the gradient should remain fixed. That's it. Because that's what the use of this property.

```
<style>
    body
    {
        background: linear-gradient(skyblue, orange);
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: could you demonstrate your problem through a fiddle?

Comment: Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/nd0o7mcb/

As you can see in this code, the gradient is stretching.

Remove background-attachment property, and it will repeat.

Now you got the question?

Comment: Have you tried a small example where it doesn't work the way you expect it to? Do not link to external resources. Just put the relevant code in your question. If you don't improve your question, it is very likely to be closed soon.

Comment: Yes this seems weird @Vipulcoolrule

Comment: Background size does not work either

Comment: @abhitalks why dont you help us then :)

Comment: @Anubhav: For that, the question needs to be improved. The Op has to include the code he has written in the question and explain what he is doing and what he is expecting. I shall write the answer, but that doesn't help the purpose of this site.

Comment: Check the fiddle out. It is self explanatory

Comment: @Vipulcoolrule please add the fiddle to your question

Comment: I edited the main post with code. @abhitalks yes I am trying this since 3 hours. Working on gradients this good morning.

Comment: @Vipulcoolrule: Now that is a better question. I have added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say:

> "...But when we add gradient as a background on body tag, it stretches
>   to entire page. Now I have studied that gradients are supposed to work
>   like that. ..."

You are wrong. Gradients are ***not*** supposed to work like that. A gradient is just a `background-image`. That's it. They behave like background images because they *are* background images.

The reason, you see that behaviour is *not* because they are supposed to work like that. The reason the work like that is because they are images. But, you haven't defined the size explicitly. So, without an explicit size, they can't have an intrinsic size. Which is why they match size of the element they are in.

From this Ref: *https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient*

> .. Like any other gradient, a CSS linear gradient is not a CSS
>   color but an image with no intrinsic dimensions; that is, it has
>   neither natural or preferred size, nor ratio. Its concrete size will
>   match the one of the element it applies to...

In order to achieve what you want, you need to apply all properties relating to `background-image`. Specifically, the `background-size`, `background-position`. Once that is done, you need to define your gradient.

***Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/comsxw8m/***

***Snippet with relevant CSS:***

```css
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #00f 100%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 120px 120px;
    background-position: top center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

### Example 2:

***See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/comsxw8m/1/***

Here the gradient is applied to body with a fixed size and is repeated. Another gradient is applied to a `div` which is `fixed`. Hope now you get the idea clearer.

***Snippet 2***:

```css
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #0ff 100%);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: 64px 64px;
}

div {
    width: 240px; height: 240px;
    margin: 32px auto;
    overflow: auto;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #00f 100%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 120px 120px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></div>
```

Comment: "By default, the gradient will stretch to fill the element it is defined on." - developers.mozilla.org

Your answer still didn't help much. Why gradients stretches when we apply background-attachment property only?

I mean, it should appear one time only and then it should remain fixed. Shouldn't it?

Comment: I'll give some time to think on your answer. I'll comment back if I still have any doubt.

Comment: @Vipulcoolrule: Referring to the documentation, it says: *".. Like any other gradient, a CSS linear gradient is not a CSS <color> but an image with no intrinsic dimensions; that is, it has neither natural or preferred size, nor ratio. Its concrete size will match the one of the element it applies to..."*. Here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Comment: So, `background-attachment` has no meaning on its size at all. It depends only on `background-size` and `background-position` and `background-repeat`.

Comment: @Vipulcoolrule: There, I have added that to the answer. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: So a gradient is an image? Lets take an image for example. 200 x 100. 200 pixels horizontally and 100 pixels vertically. Now lets apply that image to `background-image` property and lets also apply `background-attachment` property to `fixed`. That image will be repeated horizontally and vertically. But a gradient can't repeat horizontally because it is filling completely. But what about vertically? Why doesn't it repeat vertically just like the image does. Why does it stretch nicely on entire page? I am sorry I am still confused. Why doesn't that happen with images?

Comment: @Vipulcoolrule: The words *"..Its concrete size will match the one of the element it applies to.."* are the key here. It takes up the size of the element. So if element is 200x200, the size of the background will be 200x200. This gives you the illusion that it is stretched. You have to specifically assign `repeat` to understand that. I will create a fiddle to demo that too.

Comment: "So if element is 200x200, the size of the background will be 200x200. This gives you the illusion that it is stretched" I see. That is starting to make some sense now.

Comment: @Vipulcoolrule: I have added another example to the answer. I hope that will make it clearer to you.

Comment: I don't get it. In your example, you have explicitly provided all those `background-xxx` properties. I still don't get why I am getting this behavior on default settings?

Comment: @Vipulcoolrule: Don't get confused. Just keep in mind one thing: "background images are images". If a regular image (jpg/png) is there then it has fixed dimensions in pixels. Right? But, when you define a gradient and don't provide a size in pixels, then what would be the dimensions? See, now the browser gets confused and according to specs, it applies the size of the element to it. If you provide a `background-size`, then it will apply your size.

Comment: So is that why the gradient gets stretched when I use `background-attachment: fixed` property? And when I don't, it repeats vertically. But when a jpg/png image is used, it repeats on both cases. Because that image has a size and it cannot get stretched without we providing its size explicitly. I see. Alright. Does `background-attachment` property manipulate the size of body tag vertically? IF NOT, then the gradient should appear only one time filling the entire size ONLY HORIZONTALLY? I hope you got what I am trying to say.

Comment: @Vipulcoolrule: NO. I have been trying to explain you that `background-attachment` has nothing to do with it! It is the `background-size`. [See this comment of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27032405/why-background-attachment-fixed-makes-the-gradient-to-appear-on-entire-page/27032598?noredirect=1#comment42587007_27032598). Why don't you try out experimenting in the fiddle. See, I have removed `background-attachment` in my last fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/comsxw8m/2/

Comment: @Vipulcoolrule: The repetition is controlled by `background-repeat`. The size is controlled by `background-size`. The position is controlled by `background-position`. The attachment is controlled by `background-attachment`. Is that really hard to undertand? :)

Comment: @Vipulcoolrule: Maybe the linear gradient is confusing you. See this fiddle with a radial gradient. Hope this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/comsxw8m/3/

Comment: Alright. On the basis of your fiddle, I did some changes and made this: http://jsfiddle.net/mc278udw/4/ On body tag, it repeats, On div tag, it doesn't. BTW Can you first of all tell me why does it repeats on body? Is it because the body is ending 100px below the div tag? And if body is ending there, why does the gradient repeats? It is applied on body tag, not HTML tag. Can you please clear this confusion first. I think the rest will be solved if I understand this.

Comment: That is because, body has no implicit height. The body element isn't actually as tall as the browser window. It's only as tall as the content inside it. So it picks up the initial window height. But when you scroll (or change the window size), it will repeat (because by default background-repeat is repeat). div on the other hand has a fixed height and hence the background doesn't repeat because it is of the same height as div.

Comment: Give `html` and `body` a height (full viewport) and then see: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/mc278udw/9/

Comment: I tried that one before making this question. :) BTW I'll give more time to this thing tomorrow. Have some other work to do. Thanks a lot for your continuous time and help bro. I have a question. I'll ask tomorrow. If you are active on FB, can you please send me a message? After URL, add this: vipulcoolrule

Comment: I finally got it after few days of research and reading specs. Whenever we apply background to `body` tag, it moves automatically to `HTML` tag and background of `body` tag gets removed. Second: Height of `HTML` tag is very less. I confirmed it using offsetHeight in JavaScript. So the reason it repeats is because the background is applied on `HTML` tag and `HTML` tag height is very less. offsetHeight shows 8 pixels. And hence when we specify min-height to 100% to HTML tag, the background stretches because the minimum height of HTML tag is 100% and BACKGROUND IS APPLIED ON `HTML` TAG

Comment: And may I know which *spec* you are referring to?

Comment: CSS 2.1 Specification. Chapter 14 Colors and backgrounds. Section 14.2 THE BACKGROUND.

Comment: And where in that section is this written: *Whenever we apply background to body tag, it moves automatically to HTML tag and background of body tag gets removed* ???

Comment: I said that in my own words. Do you really think they will make specs in this language? They make specs considering every possible outcomes and hence they sound complicated. Here you go: For documents whose root element is an HTML "HTML" element or an XHTML "html" element that has computed values of 'transparent' for 'background-color' and 'none' for 'background-image', user agents must instead use the computed value of the background properties from that element's first HTML "BODY" element or XHTML "body" element child when painting backg,.. The comment is too long. Read remaining from specs.

Comment: Continued: ... painting backgrounds for the canvas, and must not paint a background for that child element.

Comment: If the HTML do not contain any background, (which is, by default), then it will use background of body tag and background of body tag will be removed. This user also said this in his own way in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806691/background-color-of-body-tag-applied-to-the-whole-html

Comment: Yes. You are right about that. But, it has to be read and interpreted in context. If you read carefully it says *...when painting backgrounds for the canvas...*. And this http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/intro.html#canvas talks about canvas being the *the space where the formatting structure is rendered.. user agents rendering to a screen generally impose a minimum width and choose an initial width based on the dimensions of the  viewport.* So, it is not like the background gets transferred to html. It is painted on the canvas.

Comment: But, yes you have raised a good point. Thank you for that. I will try and get some expert advice on what constitutes a canvas.

Comment: Oh I see. I'll check it out. :)