# background color for body element with predefined height in css

Tags: html, css

I have a html page which looks like this

```css
body {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <p> First para </p>
  <p> Second para </p>

</body>

</html>
```

Here I specified body `height` as `200px` and `background-color` for body element as "lightblue". 
Why is the `background-color` for body getting applied to the whole page and not only `200px` height of the body?

Comment: [CSS-Tricks.com: Just One of Those Weird Things About CSS: Background on <body>](https://css-tricks.com/just-one-of-those-weird-things-about-css-background-on-body/)

Comment: This is a very good explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/17817919/2894798

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In the absence of a background on the html element, the body background will cover the page. If there is a background on the html element, the body background behaves just like any other element.

*Source: [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/just-one-of-those-weird-things-about-css-background-on-body/)*

So, to prevent this, you can simply define `background-color:white` for `html`.

```css
html {
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <p> First para </p>
  <p> Second para </p>

</body>

</html>
```